# how to move icons to center

Tags: yii2, navbar

i have navigation bar, code is below...

```
 <?php
        NavBar::begin(['brandLabel' => '',
                    'options' => [  //'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
                                    'style' => 'height: 30px; margin-top:-10px;',]
                                ]);
        echo Nav::widget([
                    'items' => [['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],],
                    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav','style' => 'align:center',],
                                ]);
        NavBar::end();
        ?>
```

is it possible to move the nave icons to center?..
bootstrap navbar-left, navbar-right is working correclty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own ID in the menu

```
<?php
NavBar::begin(['brandLabel' => '',
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar navbar-fixed-top clients',
            'id' => 'my-menu',
        ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'items' => [['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],],
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav', 'style' => 'align:center',],
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

and do whatever you want with css

```
div#my-menu-collapse ul li {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one should work, better to move inline css to some class.

```
NavBar::begin(['brandLabel' => '',
                'options' => [  //'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
                                'style' => 'height: 30px; margin-top:-10px;',]
                            ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
                'items' => [['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],],
                'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav','style' => 'display: flex;justify-content: center;float: none;',],
                            ]);
    NavBar::end();
```